# ADO.NET Entity Framework In A COM Visible VB.NET Class Library

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, com, vb6

At first I didn't think something like this would be possible but I am testing the waters.

I created a COM Class library in VB6 and then registered it on my machine running VB6 then was able to reference it and access its properties and functions from within a VB6 app.

The next thing I tried was adding an ADO.NET Entity Framework Model to this class library, which also adds an app.config with a conn string called test_comContext. I compiled it and sent it over to the VB6 machine and try to call a function involving it and I am getting the following error:

*No connection string named 'test_comContext' could be found in the application config file.*

I am assuming it is referring to my VB6 application because the connection string is definitely in the libraries app.config.

Any recomendations/opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6 is likely to be using ADO while VB.NET/C# would be using ADO.NET.  They are two different data access technologies and there are going to be differences in their connectionstring formats.  If you really need/want to connect to the database from the VB6 COM code you'll need an additional connection string in your app.config and have your managed code read that string and pass it to your COM method as an argument.

Comment: Great thanks,. By managed code you mean my library code in VS2013 or VB6 app code?

Comment: Managed, in this context, means your .NET library (as opposed to your VB6 COM binaries).